# Delete multiple XML nodes in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to remove multiple nodes that a particular `element(path)` contains a value but I'm receiving a `System.NullReferenceException` any help where I'm going wrong would I'be much appreciated.

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ApplicationData Version="12.5.1" RootPath="FireFox-FILES">
  <RegistrySystem>
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Temp\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Temp\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList\MM.EXE" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Temp\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList\plugin-container.exe" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Temp\Microsoft\MediaPlayer">
      <ENTRY Name="" Value="43.0.4" Type="1" />
      <ENTRY Name="CurrentVersion" Value="43.0.4 (x86 en-GB)" Type="1" />
    </DIR>
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList\plugin-container.exe" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList2\plugin.exe" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList2\container.exe" />
    <DIR Operation="+" Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList4">
      <ENTRY Name="" Value="43.0.4" Type="1" />
      <ENTRY Name="CurrentVersion" Value="43.0.4 (x86 en-GB)" Type="1" />
    </DIR>
  </RegistrySystem>
</ApplicationData>
```

My code looks like this:

```cs
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlFile);
foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants("DIR").Where(status => status.Attribute("Path").Value.Contains(@"C:\Temp\")))
{
    node.Remove();

}
xdoc.Save(XmlFile);
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: Is it possible that `xdoc` is null after the attempt to load it from the XML file?

Comment: Sorry I mean where Attribute.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any `DIR` elements without a `Path` attribute? That would certainly cause the problem... Also note that you can just call `Remove()` on a query returning a sequence of elements, and it will remove then all :)

Comment: This *isn't* really a duplicate of the canonical question. The exception is thrown within framework code in a very non-obvious way. The normal kind of diagnostics don't help.

Comment: OK, I recreatd this. When first node is Remove  and I want to get next value in foreach loop code is throw NullReferenceException. First node can by Removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting the exception, but I strongly suspect it's because you're modifying the document while you're querying it.

If you change your code to use a `ToList()` call to get the list of nodes to remove, that doesn't throw:

```cs
foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants("DIR")
           .Where(status => status.Attribute("Path").Value.Contains(@"C:\Temp\"))
           .ToList())
{                                                                            
    node.Remove();
}
```

However, that's not the best way. The best approach is to use the [`Remove(this IEnumerable<XElement>)` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
xdoc.Descendants("DIR")
    .Where(status => status.Attribute("Path").Value.Contains(@"C:\Temp\"))
    .Remove();
```

No need for a `foreach` loop at all. Now to make it robust in the face of `DIR` elements without a `Path` attribute, you can cast to string instead:

```cs
xdoc.Descendants("DIR")
    .Where(status => ((string) status.Attribute("Path") ?? "").Contains(@"C:\Temp\"))
    .Remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, adding the .Remove() on the end of the query and removing it out the for loop fixed it i suspect your right that i was trying to modify the document while querying it. added the ?? to handle null vales aswell. Thanks for your help...